# Why isn't my embedded video fitting in mobile view after changing the width of the column to a 100%

Tags: html, css, width

So my code is a simple site it has a container which includes a row and inside the row there is col-6    with 2 other classes inside leftside-col and rightside-col. ihave set col-6 to have a width of 50%  but in mobile mode it should have a width of 100% in a course video i saw that this would let the video stack on top of the text however when i open inspector tool it stays at 50% and even when i edit it in desktop view to 100% to test it out it doesnt stack over it what am i doing wrong

here is my html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
        <head>
<title> My CSS Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="first-site.css">        
</head>

    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="topnav " id="dropdownClick">
                <li> <a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#News">News</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#About">About</a></li>
                <li class="topnav-right"> <a href="#Sign Up">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li class="topnav-right"> <a href="#Sign in">Sign in</a></li>
                <li class="dropdownIcon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dropdownMenu()">&#9776;</a></li>
            </ul>
                
            </nav>

<div class="container" id="section-1-gradient">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6 ">
<div class="leftside-col">
<h1 class="large">Crazy Radness</h1>
<h1 class="large">Made for developers </h1>
</div>
<form>
<div class="leftside-col">    
    <h2> Username</h2>
    <input class="inputbox" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"> 
    <h2>Password</h2>
    <input class="inputbox" name="pass" type="text" placeholder="Password"> 

</div>

</form>

</div>
<div class="col-6">
<div class="rightside-col">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dldb019Co2I?si=mZ_KwLhNwGUhWxr4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

    </body>

<script>
function dropdownMenu() {
   var x = document.getElementById("dropdownClick") ;
if(x.className === "topnav"){
    x.className += " responsive";
}
else{
    x.className = "topnav";
}
    /* change topnav to topnav.responsive */
}

</script>

</html>
```

and this is my css code

```
/*#######   defaults    #######*/
nav,header,footer{
display: block;
}
/*  */
body{
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 4%;
padding-bottom: 4%;
}
/*******************custom styles   ******************/
#section-1-gradient {
   background: #076dff;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#076dff,#65A5FF);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(#076dff,#65A5FF);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(#076dff,#65A5FF);
   background: linear-gradient(#076dff,#65A5FF);

}

div.leftside-col{
    margin-left:  30%;
}

div.rightside-col{
    margin-left: 15%;
}

h1.large{
color: #fff;
font-size: 56px;
margin: 0%;
line-height: 70px;

}

input[type="text"]{
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;

}

form h2 {
    color: white;
}


.row{
width: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;

}

.row::after{
display: table;
clear: both;
content: "";

}
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width:33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

/*#######   Nav Bar    #######*/
nav{
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
nav ul{
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.topnav li{
list-style: none;
float: left;
}

ul.topnav li.topnav-right {
    float: right;
}

ul.topnav li a{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
min-height: 16px;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #666;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover{
background-color: #0080ff;
color: white;
}

ul.topnav li.dropdownIcon{
    display: none;
}

/* ###  mobile  ### */
@media screen and (max-width: 680px){
    ul.topnav li:not(:nth-child(1)){
        display: none;
    }
    
    ul.topnav li.dropdownIcon{
display: block;
float: right;
    }
ul.topnav.responsive li.dropdownIcon{
    position: absolute;
top:0;
right: 0;
}

 ul.topnav.responsive{
    position: relative;
 }
 ul.topnav.responsive li{
display: inline;
float: none;
}
ul.topnav.responsive li a {
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
.col-6 {
    width: 100%;
margin: 0cm;
}
}
```

im trying to set the second col-6 to 100% width in mobile mode so that it stacks on the 1st column and it still stays at 50% and doesn't stack

Comment: Viewport Meta Tag: Ensure that your HTML includes the viewport meta tag in the <head> section. This tag is essential for responsive designs to work correctly on mobile devices. It should look like this:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> because i can't find that in your html

Comment: @AdesojiAlu I added it but it still didn't fix the issue  edit: actually it did make the media part get detected it turned to 100% but it still doesn't do what i want it to do so it's a start

Comment: if there is a way you can send me the whole code, i will asssit you